# Can't get a coroutine to work to change player speed?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a speed boost empty game object that has a SpeedBoost script attached to it, and a prefab game object as a child of it. When my player makes contact with the speed boost, a `coroutine` immediately starts inside `OnTriggerEnter` which both increases the players speed for a set time and temporarily deactivates the speed boost object from the scene. Once the timer is up, the speed boost is reverted to default and `SetActive` turns from `false` to `true`.

The problem is that rather than the players walk speed, run speed and crouch speed all being boosted, only the crouch speed is boosted which is extremely confusing to me. I have tried to reorder the code, I have tried to delete the crouch speed boost portion and I have double checked to make sure that all 3 "boosted" values are all higher than the default values, and they are. There is no code interfering with this as I have another similar speed boost type object (with no coroutine) that slows down the player and it works.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        StartCoroutine(RespawnSpeedBoost());
    }
}

IEnumerator RespawnSpeedBoost()
{
    // reference movement script to get the speed values
    movement.walkSpeed = boostedWalkSpeed; // 12f
    movement.sprintSpeed = boostedSprintSpeed; // 12f
    movement.crouchSpeed = boostedCrouchSpeed; // 8f
    speedBoost.SetActive(false);        
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    speedBoost.SetActive(true);
    movement.walkSpeed = walkSpeed; // 4f
    movement.sprintSpeed = sprintSpeed; // 6f
    movement.crouchSpeed = crouchSpeed; // 2f
}
```

Comment: thren you need to debug whats going on, if one works the rest should work as they were done first - it woudl imply the numbers are not the numbers you thought it would be

Comment: I've debugged and manually set the values without using any variable names to see if that was the issue and it's not

Comment: the only other option is that script is not compiled - it wont skip lines because its bored

Comment: Show the `movement` script, might be something there. Also, could the `OnTrigger` happen again before the coroutine runs out? In which case you should stop the existing coroutine (assign it as a variable) before starting it again. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html